# svg inside dev in flexbox overflowing and seems bigger than specified width and height

Tags: html, css

The SVG box inside a div is the width and height of the div element it is in and i don't know why. I am using flexboxes.  I am using css or specifying directly the width and height specifically for all the elements which is why I am posting this question cause that is not working.  I am trying for a 30 by 30 px svg inside a div that is 70 by 100 and it is overflowing and way bigger for whatever reason.

html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="div left-1" id="drawArea">  
         <svg class="test" width:"30px" height:"30px" viewbox=viewBox="0 0 30 30"> 
         </svg>
     </div>
    <div class="div right-1">2</div>         
    <div class="div left-2" >3</div>  
    <div class="div right-2">4</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {display: flex;  flex-wrap: wrap; font-weight: bold;  text-align: center; width:170px; height:200px}
.left-1 {flex-basis: 70px;  background: yellow;}
.right-1 {flex-basis: 100px;  background: deepskyblue;}
.left-2 {flex-basis: 70px;  background: hotpink;}
.right-2 {flex-basis: 100px;  background:  BlueViolet;}
.test {background: black;}
```

Also see codepen.  The black blox is the svg area
https://codepen.io/sumo_suzy/pen/MWPJWmv

Having done some more testing I realize this has nothing to do with me using flex box but the size of the svg area doesn't seem to change no matter what I put in for width or height (and i have tried with viewbox too)

See this codepen

https://codepen.io/sumo_suzy/pen/dygNPrN

Answer (score 0):

You have `width:"30px"` , replace it with `width="30"`. Same for height
Furthermore in your case you are not using svg, you could use a div rather than svg tag, indeed you can remove `viewport` attribute

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use svg you have to follow svg rules...

see the snippet there after from yours. Mainly it's "syntax" problems

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 170px;
  height: 200px
}

.left-1 {
  flex-basis: 70px;
  background: yellow;
}

.right-1 {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.left-2 {
  flex-basis: 70px;
  background: hotpink;
}

.right-2 {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background: BlueViolet;
}

.test {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div left-1" id="drawArea">
    <svg class="test" style="width:30px;height:30px" viewBox="0 0 30 30"></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="div right-1">2</div>
  <div class="div left-2">3</div>
  <div class="div right-2">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried changing the size to 60 by 60.  It should fit within a height of 100 but appears to be expanding the height of the top divs

https://codepen.io/sumo_suzy/pen/MWPJWmv

Comment: yes it is, but that normal, it's what your code is doing! What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the second row and first row to increase proportionally at the same rate even though there is a SVG inside one of the div tags.   It manages to work where i am actually doing it when the SVG tag is not inside there.  And why did it think it had to increase the first row?   The SVG area is smaller than the height of the div.   I have also tried setting the flex grow and shrink to zero

Comment: try to use grid instead of flex. Grid give a 2 dimensions structure not flex. You define size of an outer container. Inside you have a grid 2 x 2, 100%

Answer (score 0):

The way  works is not as straightforward as sometime one might think.

[See this for details](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/).

Basically, you want to scale your svg using css, so just add width and height properties to your class test css like the other answers have mentioned/done:

```
.test {
   ...
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
}
```

Then your svg should size just right.